# how to distinguish the transaction status from the total transactions that I got, for example 10 total transactions, 3 successful 3 pending 4 failed,

Tags: php, laravel

```
DB::table('covis_transactions as a')
       
->leftJoin('covis_customers as b', 'a.covis_customer_id','b.id')
       
->leftJoin('companies as c', 'b.company_id', 'c.id')
       
->leftJoin('projects as d', 'b.project_id', 'd.id')
       
->leftJoin('branchs as e', 'b.branch_id', 'e.id')
       
->leftJoin('regions as f', 'b.region_id', 'f.id')
       
->whereBetween('a.visited_at', [$from, $to])
       
->where('e.is_active', 1)
       
->select(
           
'a.status as status',
           
'b.name as customer_name',
           
'e.name as branch_name',
           
'c.name as company_name',
           
'd.name as project_name',
           
'f.name as region_name',
           
'e.code as branch_code',
           
'e.id as branch_id',
            
DB::raw('COUNT(a.id) as total_transaksi'),
           
)
           
->groupBy(
            
'branch_id',
            
'customer_name',
            
'branch_name',
            
'branch_code',
            
'status', 
            
'company_name',
            
'project_name',
            
'region_name',
           )
          
->get();
```

i want at my row table :

```
total_transaksi     
10

transaksi_success    
4

transaksi_failed 

4    

transakisi_pending

2
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.